# Does Madhwa say that some souls will be eternally damned even if they do good deeds?

Tags: madhwa

It says in Quora that according to Madhwa

> The souls are divided according to 3 different classes

> Satvic & mukti Yogyas: These souls are born certified as the highest class with the guaranteed eligibility of liberation & a place in hell. They can go through many lives doing whatever they wish without fear of divine punishment as ultimately they end up in a good place.

> Nitya Samsaras: They will go through eternal cycles of life & death without recourse to any final resolution or destination for all their efforts.

> Tamo-Yogyas: These are the ones destined for eternal damnation, they get created with a one way highway to hell. They can do all the good things and be the best of people but they’re damned as hell. They go through various lifetimes with various karmic dynamics but finally end up in hell.

And when Pralaya occurs, will these souls be released from eternal damnation according to Madhwa?

Comment: Your question is not logical. 'Eternally' means forever, regardless of Pralaya occurring. To be redeemed after Pralaya does not mean eternal.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda The vedas are said to be "eternal" because they re-occur every kalpa though.

Comment: someone voted to close this as "Needs details or clarity: This question should include more details and clarify the problem." maybe you can add more details to prevent closure. one line questions can be a bit confusing :P